# What is the maximum number of spheres each with radius $1$ cm can be packed in the cuboid?

Tags: solid-geometry

> Acuboid with length $10$ cm  width  $8$ cm  and height  $2\pi $ ,
>   What is the maximum number  of spheres each  with radius $1$ cm can be packed in the cuboid ?

I searched the web and found a lot of talking about this kind of problems , different and different approaches
>

> Why is that ? And what is the proper approache to this problem?

Please elaborate your answer so that i can understand it

Thank you for your help

Comment: Hint: The maximum packing density of equal spheres (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing) is $\frac{\pi}{3 \sqrt2}$. Using this, what is the maximum number of spheres that can be packed into a box?

Comment: @Toby Mak  $88$?

Comment: Use that as an upper bound for your calculation.

Comment: The cubic lattice (on the same page) has a density of $\pi/6$, so since there are $10 * 8 * \lfloor (2 \pi) \rfloor $ or $480$ cubes that can fit in the cuboid, then a better estimate would be $480 * (\pi * 1/6) / (4/3 * \pi)$ spheres, which is about $60$ spheres. This can be the lower bound of your calculation.